# Could anyone help me to find my mistake in this problem? Thank you

Tags: c#, arrays

**Condition: 1. Train**

> A train has an **n** number of wagons (integer, received as input). On the next `n` lines, you will receive the amount of people that are going to get on each wagon. Print out the *number of passengers in each wagon* followed by the *total number* of passengers on the train.

**Examples:**

```
Input   Output
3
13
24
8       13 24 8
        45

6
3
52
71
13
65
4       3 52 71 13 65 4
        208

1
100     100
        100
```

**My code:**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Arrays___Exercise
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] wagons = new int[n];
            int p = 0;
            
            for (int i = 0; i < wagons.Length; i++)
            {
                wagons[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                p += wagons[i];

            }

            Console.WriteLine(p);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO use a class that represents a `Wagon` that holds a count of `Passengers`, keep a `List<Wagon>` with these details. To get/print anything you need is easy at this point.

Comment: @zaggler _"Arrays___Exercise"_

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen yes, it seems that way :)

Comment: But: Array Lesson #1: Avoid them for List<T>

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: You should *print out* array's *items*, now you print the total only. You can implement a `for` loop for this

Comment: OP should add `Console.Write(wagons[i] + " ");` on the empty line in the for loop.

Comment: you actually calculated the sum of the passengers but you forgot to print the number of passengers from each wagon. You are missing a Console.WriteLine inside you input loop

Comment: @TaW Step by step OP will grow to `List<T>`. Start at the basics

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen please prefer "you", "they", "OP" etc

Comment: @TaW it's not for us to dictate the syllabus a student is following..

Answer (score -1):

This is clearly homework, and I've done a lot of my own homework in the time so I'm not going to do it exactly.. But I don't mind offering some tips

Everything looks good, it's just that you need a loop that runs over your `wagons` and prints out each wagon's population:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < wagons.Length; i++)
        {
            wagons[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            p += wagons[i];
        }


        *** PUT A LOOP IN HERE TO PRINT THE CONTENTS OF THE WAGONS ***


        Console.WriteLine(p);
```

- You can use a for loop that is exactly the same as the previous loop that also loops over `wagons`.
- You can use `Console.Write` instead of WriteLine, if you don't want your output to go onto the next line
- You can use `Console.WriteLine()` on its own (without anythign in the parentheses) to move to a new line without printing anything
- Print every wagon content with a space after it, e.g. `Console.Write(wagon[i] + " ");
- You might look at it and go "oh, those two loops are essentially the same, i'll just put the Write inside the earlier loop", but then that will cause a messed up output if you try and read and write in the same loop
- After you've done a really basic output you might want to flair it up a little, draw some ascii art train or something ;)

```
   OO O o o o...       ______________   ______________   ______________
  O     ____          |              | |              | |              |
 ][_n_i_| (   ooo___  |      13      | |      24      | |      8       |  = 45
(__________|_[______]_|______________|_|______________|_|______________|
  0--0--0      0  0       0     0          0     0          0     0
```

Ok, maybe not that complex, but in reality it's not so difficult.. this is just repeatedly using Console.Write to output fixed lumps of text, occasionally with a variable number. If the lines of the engine are in one array, the lines of a wagon in another array, it's just about using loops to print the top line of the engine, then the top line of N carraiges, then the next line of the engine, then the next line of N carraiges..

..you'll be fair sick of loops and arrays by the end of it :D